# running sqlplus from within Julia

Tags: julia, sqlplus

I'm a very beginner Julia user but would like to use it for some of my projects.

Many of my projects require me to make a quick connection to Oracle to get an ID number of some other data.  I can do this by running sqlplus from other programs like shell or tcl, but I've tried the syntax in the Julia documentation, but always get one error or another.

In Tcl it looks something like this

```
exec sqlplus -s user/pass@dbname << "
            SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
            select ID from table1 where name='abc';
            exit;
            "
```

From julia, I'm trying to use the run command like this

```
run(`sqlplus -s user/pass@dbname << "
   SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
   select ID from table1 where name='abc';
   exit;
   "
   `)
```

but I get various errors from Julia like

```
Stacktrace:
[1] depwarn(::String, ::Symbol) at ./deprecated.jl:70
[2] warn_shell_special(::String) at ./shell.jl:8
[3] #shell_parse#236(::String, ::Function, ::String, ::Bool) at ./shell.jl:103
[4] (::Base.#kw##shell_parse)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#shell_parse, ::String, ::Bool) at ./<missing>:0 (repeats 2 times)
[5] @cmd(::ANY) at ./process.jl:796
[6] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
[7] eval_user_input(::Any, ::Base.REPL.REPLBackend) at ./REPL.jl:66
[8] macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:97 [inlined]
[9] (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:73
```

Any help from anyone?

Comment: try the `pipeline` command instead of `<<`

Comment: already tried that.  I get an error like "could not spawn sqlplus -s user/pass@dbname.  no such file or directory"

Comment: Jon: to me this particular error means `sqlplus` is not in the path / accessible from your julia environment. I.e. it has nothing to do with the particular syntax you used (obviously this doesn't mean that if you put it in the path, it will immediately work, since the syntax may also be slightly wrong).

Comment: alternatively, you may be passing that string to your pipeline, which julia interprets as an input filename to pipe from, so naturally it complains there's no such file. If this is the case, try `echo`ing the string instead, and using that as the input to your pipeline

Comment: no, that's not the case.  That's the first thing I checked.  I've tried the fully qualified path with the same errors.  and some variation of the  backticks, I do get an sqlplus error, which means that sqlplus is correctly defined in the julia environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function which works on my machine, it also returns the output of `sqlplus` command in a variable (if this is needed). If the output is not needed, a simpler solution might be available.

```
sqlplus_script = """
   SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
   select ID from table1 where name='abc';
   exit;
"""

sqlplus_cmd = `sqlplus -s user/pass@dbname`
# sqlplus_cmd = `cat`         # used for testing

function stringpipe(cmd,instring)
    inpipe = Pipe()
    outpipe = Pipe()
    p = spawn(pipeline(cmd,stdin=inpipe,stdout=outpipe))
    write(inpipe, instring)
    close(inpipe)
    close(outpipe.in)
    s = read(outpipe,String)
    return s
end

println(stringpipe(sqlplus_cmd, sqlplus_script))
```

It is mostly self-explanatory (BTW using Julia version 0.6 but should probably work on 0.5).

Comment: here is the error that I get from running this.     ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Type{String} to an object of type Array{UInt8,1}
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Array{UInt8,1}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.

Comment: 1. which version Julia are you using? 2. where is the MethodError in the script? 3. Is it doing the error when running the script "as is" with `sqlplus_cmd = \`cat\`` instead of `sqlplus`?

Comment: I'm using released version of 0.6.  I'm using sqlplus_cmd as sqlplus, not as `cat' but I get this error with both.  I'm not sure about your question #2.  How do I know where the MethodError is coming from?

Comment: OK, I've managed to reproduce the error when using version 0.5. Try substituting `read(output,String)` with `readstring(outpipe)`. There is an ongoing change in the API.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  but should you modify the code in the original answer so that it is correct in the accepted answer?

Comment: I'm leaving the code as is, since it does run on 0.7 (latest currently) and it's better to prepare answers for the future ;)